# Solving Sturmian Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

How to solve this linear pde for $y(x)$ (other functions are known and $\lambda$ is a constant):$$\frac{d}{d x}(g(x)y'(x))=\lambda ^2g(x)y(x)$$ Everything I know about this equation is that it is called the Sturmian equation. I did some research, but the theory, which is for a more general form of the equation, is too hard for me to understand.

Comment: I removed the "pde" tag and added "differential-equations" and "sturm-liouville"; the equation would not generally be considered a PDE. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. It was my bad to pick the pde tag. This is a sub-problem from separation of variable of a pde problem, which is the reason I mistakenly picked the wrong tag.

Comment: Also, the equation is *linear* in $y(x)$.

Comment: I corrected it. I totally thought it was non-linear at first sight...

Comment: This the general form of second order linear homogeneous ODE : $$k_1(x)y''(x)+k_2(x)y'(x)+k_3(x)y(x)=0$$ $k_1(x)=g(x)\quad;\quad k_2(x)=g'(x)\quad;\quad k_3(x)=-\lambda^2h(x)$. Be more specific about the functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? This is a second order ODE $gy''+g'y'-\lambda^2hy=0$. If $g$ does not vanish on $[a,b]$, then you have two linearly independent solutions on $[a,b]$ by general results of ODEs. Closed form solutions are unlikely except in special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the operator
$$
                Lf = \frac{1}{g}\frac{d}{dx}\left(g\frac{df}{dx}\right).
$$
You want to solve $Lf=\lambda^2 f$. Start by solving for $f_0$ such that
$$
     Lf_0=0,\;\; f_0(0)=A,\; f_0'(0)=B.
$$
This is done by integrating the following in $x$:
$$
          \frac{d}{dx}\left(g\frac{df_0}{dx}\right)=0 \\
         g\frac{df_0}{dx}-g(0)B=0 \\
        \frac{df_0}{dx} = \frac{Bg(0)}{g(x)} \\
          f_0(x)=A+B\int_{0}^{x}\frac{g(0)}{g(x)}dx.
$$
Then recursively solve
$$
                  Lf_n = f_{n-1},\;\; f_n(0)=0,\;\; f_n'(0)=0,\;\;\; n \ge 1.
$$
This is done by integrating:
$$
            \frac{1}{g}\frac{d}{dx}\left(g\frac{df_{n}}{dx}\right)=f_{n-1},\;\; f_n(0)=0,\;f_n'(0)=0 \\
            g\frac{df_n}{dx}=\int_{0}^{x}g(y)f_{n-1}(y)dy \\
        f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{g(z)}\int_{0}^{z}g(y)f_{n-1}(y)dy dz
$$
Now form the sum
$$
              f(x,\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{2n}f_n(x).
$$
You can verify that $f(0)=f_0(0)=A$ and $f'(0)=f_0'(0)=B$. And,
$$
       Lf = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{2n}f_{n-1}=\lambda^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{2n}f_n=\lambda^2 f.
$$